# When to use "Operator States" and what is the difference between "Keyed State" and "Session Window" in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have two questions regarding a best practice of using `states` with flink:

- **regarding operator state**

Can you explain please what a use case for the `Operator State` in Flink would look like?

When should I use it?

- **regarding "keyed state" vs "session window"**

What is the difference or advantage/disadvantage of using a keyed state instead a windowAssigner with a sessionWindow that maps into some id?

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question, You even have a sample use case for `Opeator State` in the documentation. It is Kafka Connector, basically each parallel instance of connector maintains a map of partitions and offsets. You would want to use `Operator State` each time when the state is not bound to the speicifc Key but rather to the whole operator. For example if You would like to keep all elements that have passed through this operator then You could use operator state.

As for  the second question I don't think I understand it, as the `KeyedState` and `SessionWindow` are two different things. Basically `KeyedState` allows You to keep state that is bound to the specific case. For example, if You had a system that processes transactions of a user and You wanted for example to keep the number of transactions made by each user for fraud detection purposes, then You could use `KeyedState` with some  User ID as a Key. The `SessionWidnow` is basically a window that groups all elements that occured in a specific activity session.

You can find more info [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#session-windows) and [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/stream/state/state.html#operator-state).